# Azure - Allow Web App to access KeyVault with Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I have an Azure KeyVault that is secured at the network-level. I only allow connections from 2 specific vnets/subnets.

However, I also want one of my web app (outside of the subnets) to be able to fetch secrets from the KeyVault. I added an access policy to let my Web App Get and List secrets.

I thought that setting `Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall?` would be enough to let my App Service access the KeyVault (they are in the same subscription). Apparently it's not the case.

What setting should I use to be able to keep my firewall rules and allow my web app to fetch the secrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to add your Web App’s list of “Outbound IPs” (found in the properties section of your web app’s blade) to the Key Vault’s firewall.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I was wondering if there was a more "built-in" approach, knowing that the IPs can change.

Comment: The IPs “shouldn’t” change unless something drastic happens to the host.

Comment: True, and also when it is scaled up to higher tiers. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using the Outbound IP's is the easiest option, and together with authentication limits the risk by quite a lot.

However, the most secure option is using the [vnet integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) on the webapps. This will enable you to access resources inside the VNET.
If you [whitelist this VNET in your keyvault's Firewall](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/network-security), you should be able to securely access the keyvault.